# Torus with two discs attached is not homeomorphic to a torus with an annulus attached

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is from an old comprehensive exam:

[image]

My initial thought was to argue via homotopy type: The two disks in $X_1$ are contractible, so after contraction we are left with a torus with two "pinches". I expanded these two get $X_1 \simeq T^2 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$, but I'm stuck as to how to do something similar to $X_2$. The annulus deformation retracts to the inner circle in the torus, but it's not immediately clear what to do after this contraction.

My other thought was to do something with Euler Characteristic, since attaching two discs increases the Euler Characteristic by 2, which gives a sphere. This doesn't line up with my homotopy arguments, so I'm going wrong somewhere. Would anyone know what I can do with $X_2$, and if either of my arguments for $X_1$ are incorrect?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you expand the "pinches"?

Comment: My thought was that I can expand these pinches with a closed contractible subcomplex to get my circles, however seeing this again the resulting surface isn't $T^2$. I'm thinking now it's $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^1$

Comment: I still don't understand how you get those wedges. Anyway, I recommend invariants when proving that some things are not homotopic. E.g. Euler Characteristic should work: $X_2$ is a product so computations are not hard for it.

Comment: I think I agree with $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^1$ after all.

Comment: Awesome! I realize my descriptions aren't very intelligible, so my apologies. For $X_2$ are you saying that it's a product of a torus and an annulus, because if so then the problem is immediately clear to me.

Comment: It's a product of a circle and a figure "8", like the torus is the product of two circles.